# TT how to print a string in a variable in an array?

Tags: arrays, string, variables, foreach, template-toolkit

I'm still fairly new to TT so what I'm asking might make no sense and be impossible, if so I'll find another way around it, Basically I'm using a FOREACH loop in order to run through an array of variables and build a table, it works fine but I essentially want to add in section headers and here's the problem. if I have section('string') in an array, how can I print that string?

I'll give an example of my code.

The data array to build

```
content_list=[ 

            section('First Section'),"somecontent","some_other_content", 

            section('Second Section'), "somecontent", "some_other_content" 
]
```

The build code

```
<table>

    [% FOREACH entry IN content_list %]

        [% IF entry == section %]
        <tr>
            <th> [% #this needs to output the string, ie 'First Section' %]</th>
        </tr>
        [% END %]

        <tr>
            <td>The content is: [% entry %]</td>
        </tr>

    [% END %]

</table>
```

It will recognise when the entry = section and print the th, but I can't figure out how to get it to print the string contained in the section? Any help would be much appreciated!

*(I realise there's probably an easier and more logical way around this but this is a small snippet of a large piece of code that would need altering lol)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly is `section(arg)` in your arrayref ? Is this a TT macro or is your example pseudo-code?

I appreciate you don't want to rewrite the whole thing. Is it possible to stash the section headers in a fashion that permits later identification that this is what they are, i.e.:

```
content_list=[ 
    { section => 'First Section' }, "somecontent", "some_other_content", 
    { section => 'Second Section' }, "somecontent", "some_other_content" 
];
```

and later on:

```
    [% IF entry.section %]
    <tr>
        <th> [% entry.section %]</th>
    </tr>
    [% END %]
```

If you go down this path, you might want to consider turning all the elements in the array to little hashrefs, i.e.:

```
content_list = [ 
    { content => 'First Section', section=>1 }, { content => "somecontent" },
    { content => "some_other_content" }, { content => 'Second Section', section=>1 },
    { content => "somecontent" }, { content => "some_other_content", some_flag=>1 }
];
```

Then each `entry IN content_list` can be an object with its own properties to suit.

---

Another approach would be to create a little hash of the content items you know are headers, and test for them, i.e.:

```
[% SET header = { 'First Section' => 1, 'Second Section' => 1, ... }; %]
```

and later on:

```
[% IF header.$entry %]
    <tr>
        <th>[% entry %]</th>
    </tr>
```

etc.

Comment: That first suggestion worked perfectly :) originally the section code was a TT Macro but I'm trying out a different method of building the tables for this project that should be more flexible and simpler to implement for the user lol

Thank you for your help RET :D I also appreciate the suggestion with regards to turning the array to little hashrefs but for this particular project that won't be necessary but I'll definitely keep it in mind ;) I would upvote your answer but I don't have enough reputation lol

Comment: Thanks. One of the great strengths of TT is it's ability to seamlessly handle being passed an array ref of objects, such as DBIx::Class data rows, for example. Good luck with your project.